# Module is not imported after sys.path.append()

Tags: django, python-3.x, apache2, django-2.2

I am trying to deploy my django application. 
Like many others I faced the problem of "missing" django, no module named django, though it exists.

I had to install Django of version 2, not the newest and it was installed into `'/home/ivan/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/'`.

I have my apache configured and wsgi.py looks like this:

```
"""
WSGI config for mysite project.

It exposes the WSGI callable as a module-level variable named ``application``.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/howto/deployment/wsgi/
"""

import os
import sys
sys.path.append('/home/ivan/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/')
print(sys.path)
# import /home/ivan/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django
from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application

os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'mysite.settings')

application = get_wsgi_application()
```

When I type python3 in terminal and do this:

```
>>> import django
>>> django.__path__
['/home/ivan/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django']
```

So I got my path of django module and I append it, I also tried:

```
sys.path.insert(0, '/home/ivan/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django')
```

and still I got 500 error with annoying:

```
[Tue Apr 21 13:12:41.861348 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 29470] [remote 185.201.90.67:1131] Traceback (most recent call last):
[Tue Apr 21 13:12:41.861379 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 29470] [remote 185.201.90.67:1131]   File "/var/www/mysite/mysite/wsgi.py", line 15, in <module>
[Tue Apr 21 13:12:41.861384 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 29470] [remote 185.201.90.67:1131]     from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
[Tue Apr 21 13:12:41.861397 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 29470] [remote 185.201.90.67:1131] ImportError: No module named 'django'
```

Why wsgi cannot work properly? What am I doing wrong here? 
Why interpreter cannot find a module after I forced him by sys.path.insert() ?

Huge thank in advance!

**UPDATE ONE**

`print(sys.path)` inside of wsgi returns:

```
    ['/var/www/mysite', '/usr/lib/python35.zip', '/usr/lib/python3.5', 

'/usr/lib/python3.5/plat-x86_64-linux-gnu', '/usr/lib/python3.5/lib-dynload', 

'/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages', 

'/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages',

 '/home/ivan/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/']
```

**UPDATE TWO**

Since I am trying to deploy the app, no matter how I solve it. 
Thanks to @KolaB for advice of virtualenv.

I just did it , now I have this structure:

```
├── mysite
├── requirements.txt
└── venvdjang
```

venvdjang is a dir with virtual interpreter. 
I also installed django by `source /venvdjang/bin/activate`

```
pip install -r requirements.txt
```

Now, how can I tell my wsgi and apache2 that I want to use virtualenv?

**Update Three**

Thank you all for your help!

I have a VPS with flask application in production (www.example.com)
Now I have to deploy another one web application on subdomain - django. (www.sub.example.com)

This is config for django.

```
/etc/apache2/sites-available/mysite.conf

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName sub.example.com
    ServerAlias www.sub.example.com
    ServerAdmin sub.example.com@gmail.com
    #DocumentRoot /var/www/mysite

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/mysite-error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/mysite-access.log combined

    #DocumentRoot /var/www/mysite/index.html

    WSGIDaemonProcess mysite processes=2 threads=25 python-path=/var/www/mysite
    WSGIProcessGroup mysite
    WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/mysite/mysite/wsgi.py

    Alias /robots.txt /var/www/mysite/static/robots.txt
    Alias /favicon.ico /var/www/mysite/static/favicon.ico
    Alias /static/ /var/www/mysite/static/
    Alias /static/ /var/www/mysite/media/

    <Directory /var/www/mysite/mysite>
        <Files wsgi.py>
            Require all granted
        </Files>
    </Directory>

    <Directory /var/www/mysite/static>
        Require all granted
    </Directory>

    <Directory /var/www/mysite/media>
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

and this is config for flask

```
 /etc/apache2/sites-available/FlaskApp-le-ssl.conf

<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
<VirtualHost *:443>
                ServerName www.example.com 
                ServerAdmin example.com@mywebsite.com
                WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/FlaskApp/flaskapp.wsgi
                <Directory /var/www/FlaskApp/FlaskApp/>
                        Order allow,deny
                        Allow from all
                </Directory>
                Alias /static /var/www/FlaskApp/FlaskApp/static
                <Directory /var/www/FlaskApp/FlaskApp/static/>
                        Order allow,deny
                        Allow from all
                </Directory>
                ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
                LogLevel warn
                CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
Include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-apache.conf
ServerAlias  example.com 
SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com 
--p1ai/fullchain.pem
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com--p1ai/privkey.pem
</VirtualHost>
</IfModule>
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
<VirtualHost *:80>
                ServerName example.com 
                Redirect / https://www.example.com 
                ServerAdmin admin@mywebsite.com
                WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/FlaskApp/flaskapp.wsgi
                <Directory /var/www/FlaskApp/FlaskApp/>
                        Order allow,deny
                        Allow from all
                </Directory>
                Alias /static /var/www/FlaskApp/FlaskApp/static
                <Directory /var/www/FlaskApp/FlaskApp/static/>
                        Order allow,deny
                        Allow from all
                </Directory>
                ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
                LogLevel warn
                CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
RewriteEngine on
# Some rewrite rules in this file were disabled on your HTTPS site,
# because they have the potential to create redirection loops.

# RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} = example.com 
# RewriteRule ^ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [END,NE,R=permanent]

#RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !^443$
#RewriteRule .* https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
</VirtualHost>
</IfModule>
```

OS - Ubuntu 16.04
mod_wsgi was installed a few years ago by `sudo apt-get install`

**Update Four**

I changed `WSGIDaemonProcess python-home` as @Alasdair said to `python-home=/var/www/venvdjang` but it did not work out.

Now if I run in terminal `source /var/www/venvdjang/bin/activate`

```
    (venvdjang) ivan@server:/var/www$ python
    Python 3.5.2 (default, Oct  8 2019, 13:06:37)
    [GCC 5.4.0 20160609] on linux
    Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
    >>> import django
    >>> import sys
    >>> sys.path
    ['', '/var/www/venvdjang/lib/python35.zip', '/var/www/venvdjang/lib/python3.5', 

'/var/www/venvdjang/lib/python3.5/plat-x86_64-linux-gnu', 

'/var/www/venvdjang/lib/python3.5/lib-dynload', 

'/usr/lib/python3.5', 

'/usr/lib/python3.5/plat-x86_64-linux-gnu', 

'/var/www/venvdjang/lib/python3.5/site-packages']
>>>
```

But my wsgi.py after removing all `sys.path.append()` staff still returns after `print(sys.path)` this:

```
['/var/www/venvdjang', 

'/usr/lib/python35.zip',

 '/usr/lib/python3.5', 

'/usr/lib/python3.5/plat-x86_64-linux-gnu',

 '/usr/lib/python3.5/lib-dynload', 

'/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages',

 '/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages']
```

It is like he still goes to system interpreter...
Why I cannot refer to a correct virtualenv ?

Comment: Why do you not simply use a virtual environment? If you want to mess around with paths, have you tried setting the PYTHONPATH environment variable?

Comment: Since you're having problems with Apache, please show your Apache config. If you follow the [deployment docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/deployment/wsgi/modwsgi/), you shouldn't have to change the path in the wsgi file. Use `WSGIPythonHome ` (`python-home` in daemon mode) to point to the virtual environment.

Comment: Which OS are you using, and how did you install mod-wsgi?

Comment: You're missing the `python-home=/path/to/venv` part in the `WSGIDaemonProcess` line. If you set that correctly, you shouldn't have to do any `sys.path` changes in the wsgi file.

Comment: @Ivan I am not familiar with using django and apache. I use the built in server for development and others in my team are responsible for deployment on production. Apologies

Comment: Also, make sure that you have installed `libapache2-mod-wsgi-py3` and not `libapache2-mod-wsgi`. If you have installed `libapache2-mod-wsgi`, then switching over might be tricky because you don't want to break the Flask app.

Comment: @Alasdair `python-home=/path/to/venv` should be in my case `python-home=/var/www/venvdjang` or `python-home=/var/www/venvdjang/bin/python3` ?

Comment: `python-home=/var/www/venvdjang`

Comment: @Alasdair thank you for your time. Please take a look at Update Four...

Comment: What's the exact error after adding `python-home`. Did you restart Apache after making the changes to the config?

Comment: @Alasdair The same one. `No module named django`. Maybe I should just manually  `sys.path.clear()` in my wsgi.py and then `sys.path = [the result which I got after running virtualenv python]` ? Of course I did `sudo service apache2 restart`

Comment: I'm afraid I don't have any other suggestions. You could try the sys.path.clear() approach but as I've been saying, if your Apache config is correct you shouldn't have to modify `sys.path` in the wsgi file at all.

Comment: Okay. Thank you very much! By the way sys.path.clear() solved the issue.. Can it lead to some problem in a future?

Comment: Glad you got it to work. It would be better to find a solution that didn't use `sys.path.clear()` but I can't think of any issues it would cause (apart from an import error if you've removed an entry you shouldn't have).